# Bootstrap Tooltip in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, tooltip, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I'm trying to get this done for quite some time now and i can't figure out whats wrong:

My Link:

```
<%= link_to '#', tag, class: "tag-tooltip",
                    :data => {:toggle=>"tooltip"},
                    'data-original-title' => "Hey Whats up",
                    'data-placement' => 'right'%>
```

My Javascript:

```
$('.tag-tooltip').tooltip();
```

But it's not working... What am i missing ?

**EDIT**

If i go into my Chrome Console and insert (*$('.tag-tooltip').tooltip();*) it is working.

So i guess the js file is not loading ? (I checked my application.js and i'm requiring everything.)

Comment: Do you have `$(document).ready(function(){...});` wrapped around `$('.tag-tooltip').tooltip();`?

Comment: I LITERALLY just found it and it worked.. But why do i have to wrap it ?? Is it because Turbolinks ?

Comment: because you want to make sure that the DOM is fully loaded so that all referenced elements are found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out the wrapping which worked:

```
$(document).on("ready page:change", function() {
  $('.tag-tooltip').tooltip();
});
```

**Update:**

```
$(document).on("turbolinks:load",function(){
  $('.tag-tooltip').tooltip();
})
```

With vanilla JS

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
  $('.tag-tooltip').tooltip();
});
```

Comment: It seem to be `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {/**/})` with newer turbolink versions.

Comment: $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {/**/})

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that I was loading `jquery-ui` after `bootstrap-sprockets`

In my `application.js` I changed:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery-ui
```

to

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

Then it all started working as it should.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some script in your code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(
      {container:'body', trigger: 'hover', placement:"right"}
    );   
  });
```