# Bootstraps Tooltip on RubyonRails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, tooltip

I've a problem here.
I tried to use Bootstrap's tooltip on my project with RubyonRails, but no luck.

I tried to use this solution: [Bootstrap Tooltip in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20129970/bootstrap-tooltip-in-ruby-on-rails) but still now working.

```
<%= f.input :company_name, class: "dashbaord-tooltip", :data => 
{:toggle=>"tooltip"}, 'data-original-title' => "Your company name", 'data-
placement' => 'right' %>
```

do I do it the correct way? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you call popover method for the class inside your coffee script as follow

```
jQuery ->
  $(".dashboard-tooltip").popover()
```

and below is the format (I corrected the spelling for dashboard)

```
<%= f.input :company_name, :class => 'dashboard-tooltip', data: { content: 'this is the message', placement: 'bottom', trigger: 'hover' } %>
```

Comment: @kadirJailani your welcome, can you mark your question answered by check mark beside my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the tooltip by adding `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();` in your JavaScript file and add this to your form:

```
<%= f.input :company_name, class: "dashbaord-tooltip", 'data-toggle'=>"tooltip" ,'title'=>'tooltip-text-here','data-placement' => 'right' %>
```